# Set Variable: to list value error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am new to SharePoint and am trying to assign a variable to a field in a list.This works fine on my laptop where I have SharePoint installed, but on the server where I have a replica of same list,it generates an error.

Here is a line showing the assignment and error generated.

```
Set Variable: *manager1 to value*.
```

> "manager1 to value"is placed between asterix

I don't understand, why I am getting this error. Please Help!